# Strange Linker error

Tags: c++, linker, skia

I am using `cl` compiler and `LINK` to link the code. I am getting very strange linker in the following sample code.

```
//main.cpp
int main ()
{
   Test();
}

void Test ()
{
}

//test.cpp
void Test3 ();
void Test2 ()
{
   Test3 ();
}
```

When I compile main.cpp with test.cpp, then it gives me linker error that `Test3` undefined which actually should not link. When I remove test.cpp from my makefile, then it compiles and links without any problem.

I am using skia library. Is it possible that this issue is due to skia library and some link option mismatch?

My compiler linker options are listed below:

**Compiler options:**
`/c /W4  /nologo /WL /Gr /GF /GA /Gy /GR- /vmb /EHsc /D_UNICODE /DUNICODE /D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /D_CRT_NON_CONFORMING_SWPRINTFS  /DWIN32 /D_WIN32  /MT /Z7 /O2  /GS- /Oi`

**Linker options:**
`LINK  skia_core.lib skia_utils.lib skia_effects.lib skia_images.lib skia_opts.lib skia_opts_ssse3.lib skia_ports.lib skia_sfnt.lib skia_skgpu.lib   /INCREMENTAL:NO /NOLOGO /OPT:REF /IGNORE:4098 /IGNORE:4089 /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS /FIXED:NO /NODEFAULTLIB:advapi32.lib /NODEFAULTLIB:user32.lib /NODEFAULTLIB:gdi32.lib /NODEFAULTLIB:shell32.lib /NODEFAULTLIB:comdlg32.lib /NODEFAULTLIB:version.lib /NODEFAULTLIB:mpr.lib /NODEFAULTLIB:rasapi32.lib /DEFAULTLIB:winmm.lib /NODEFAULTLIB:winspool.lib /NODEFAULTLIB:vfw32.lib /NODEFAULTLIB:secur32.lib /NODEFAULTLIB:oleacc.lib /NODEFAULTLIB:oledlg.lib /NODEFAULTLIB:sensapi.lib /NODEFAULTLIB:kernel32.lib /NODEFAULTLIB:wininet.lib /NODEFAULTLIB:wsock32.lib /NODEFAULTLIB:odbc32.lib /NODEFAULTLIB:odbccp32.lib /NODEFAULTLIB:htmlhelp.lib /NODEFAULTLIB:comctl32.lib /NODEFAULTLIB:libc.lib unicows.lib kernel32.lib user32.lib winspool.lib gdi32.lib Rpcrt4.lib netapi32.lib wininet.lib wsock32.lib odbc32.lib odbccp32.lib htmlhelp.lib comctl32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib comdlg32.lib version.lib mpr.lib rasapi32.lib winmm.lib vfw32.lib secur32.lib oleacc.lib oledlg.lib DbgHelp.lib shlwapi.lib mstask.lib taskschd.lib psapi.lib crypt32.lib /VERSION:1.0  skia_core.lib skia_utils.lib skia_effects.lib skia_images.lib skia_opts.lib skia_opts_ssse3.lib skia_ports.lib skia_sfnt.lib skia_skgpu.lib /MAP /DEBUG /OPT:REF /NODEFAULTLIB:LIBCMTD.LIB psapi.lib crypt32.lib usp10.lib Opengl32.lib Gdiplus.lib /RELEASE  /OUT:test.exe`

**Linker error message**:
`LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __fastcall Test3(void)" (?Test3@@YIXXZ) referenced in function "void __fastcall Test2(void)" (?Test2@@YIXXZ)`

Comment: Please give us the precise and complete linker error message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Function Test3 is just declared but not defined. You need to write some code for it.

You expect the linker to detect that Test3 is not needed even if it is called from Test2, because Test2 is not ever called. You cannot take that for granted as it is not guaranteed in the standard.

Comment: Please see the code execution from main. It should not get linked due to dead code elimination and therefore there should not be any linker error.

Comment: @dbasic " It should not get linked due to dead code elimination" do you have a reference for that?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: Please see /OPT:REF here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bxwfs976.aspx

Comment: @dbasic where does it say that this options allows what you're asking?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore `/OPT:REF eliminates functions and/or data that are never referenced;`

Comment: @dbasic It does not say that it can do it even in more difficult cases like yours where the non-reference is indirect.

Comment: @dbasic again, where does it say what *you're asking*? What I gather from that quote is "after everything is done (i.e. link successful), we just strip the library of unused code".

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: My unreferenced function is in a separate compilation unit. I do not think that is difficult case.